# Where are the Django and python files?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and Python, I'm coming from Laravel.

I'm working on a Windows machine.

My Laravel project has tons of folders (vendor etc.) and is >100 MB my Django project is <50kB.

In the end, I want to upload my Django project to a webserver.

But I'm curious where the Djangofiles on my computer are located, and how deployment works. (what are the essential parts/files compared to Laravel (Project Folder + DATABASE) which I've to transfer)

Is the Django Framework similar to a Javascript file, which I can put I my project folder or get via linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place you move your Django project folder to on your server is where your Django files is located. Django files might be small in size, however, to run your Django application you will need to install +100MB packages from `PIP`.

The essential part of Django is your project directory and your `requirements.txt` file in which all python package required to run your application will be listed in it.

Django is not similar to a Javascript file, Django is a complete web development framework similar to Laravel framework, you may refer to this Head-to-Head comparison between Django and Laravel: [Here](https://digitalya.co/blog/laravel-vs-django-performance-comparison/)

For more details on deployment you may refer to the following tutorials:

1. Hosting Django with Nginx: [Nginx + Django](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)
2. Hosting Django with Apache: [Apache + Django](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/hosting-django-sites-apache)